# rails: How to log response & request of 3rd party gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, external

My app using [active_shipping](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping) gem that send XML requests to several APIs and receive from these APIs an XML responses.

I would like to log on my app every response/request and API url for this external gem.

What is the best way achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the [active_shipping docs](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping#development):

> To log requests and responses, just set the logger on your carrier class to some kind of Logger object:
>
> `ActiveShipping::USPS.logger = Logger.new($stdout)`

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I've been trying that and all it logged for me is the response. I still can't see the request in logs which is super important for debugging for me.

Comment: ok weird, now I can see the request also. request is logged by the carrier itself, and probably should be on debug mode to be displayed. thanks.